# Run a query on a local SQLite file, from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, sqlite, google-chrome-extension

I want to execute queries against a **local** SQLite file, from JavaScript. How can this be done?

By local, I mean a .sqlite file on the user's computer. I do not need storage for an application, so suggestions about WebSQL are not helpful.

The use-case is, I have many local SQLite files that I use as a database for other applications. I am trying to build a Chrome Extension that lets me query the SQLite files so I can see data contents without having to use my SQLlite workbench app, which sucks.

Comment: If you're voting to close, please leave a comment explaining why. 

Usually my questions have more content, but this one really doesn't need any more details.

Comment: Why don't use [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)?

Comment: @Elad, because I'm trying to view my SQLLite db on my computer.  I don't need it to power an application

Comment: You can use WebSQLDatabase that use SQLlite in backend

Comment: @elad ... it needs to read from a SQLLite database file stored on my computer.

Comment: Do you want read only access or read/write? Do you want only a snapshot, or access to a file that's being updated by something else?

Comment: I hope this is not possible. I don't want javascript reading my filesystem (possibly) without me knowing.

Comment: If you assume this can be done the questions seems rather broad but I really doubt if this is possible so the answer on this question would be no. I retracted my close vote for now...let's see how this goes...

Comment: So, yeah, explaining why I voted to close: not enough information in the question _(despite you thinking it does not need more details)_

Comment: Thanks for the comments all - added my use-case to the question which hopefully makes it clearer what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An *extension* would not be able to do that. While you can "upload" a file to an extension, it would not retain access to the file on disk; it would be just a snapshot at the moment of an upload.

An *app*, however, can. With [`chrome.filesystem` API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem), you can request read or read/write access to a file, and *retain* the resulting entry to query it again later without dialogs to the user.

Of course, it's up to your JS code to actually read the database. There is no API for that, you need to use a library.

Comment: You can use [sql.js](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js) to access the local db file in your Chrome App. Sql.js file is big but it will be stored locally in the app.